# Storyboard Switching Views from Push Segue Crashing

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode4.5, segue, iphone-5

I have a storyboard set up with two views, one for 3.5in iPhone screens, and one for 4in iPhone screens. In the AppDelegate.m under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I have:

```
ViewController *viewc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewc performSegueWithIndentifier:@"second" sender:viewc];
```

And the Storyboard is set up like this:
[image http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/18/3317719/screenshot8.jpg](http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/18/3317719/screenshot8.jpg)
The app crashes and the error states that there is no segue with the identifier 'second' even though the image shows that the identifier is named 'second'. Do I need to programmatically create a segue? If so, how do I do this? If not, what's wrong? I am using Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Are you implementing `prepareForSegue` in `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes, but it still crashes. The code for that is `[self prepareForSegue:[UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"second" source:self destination:self performHandler:nil] sender:self];`

Answer (score 0):

You're alloc init'ing a different instance than the one in the storyboard, so it doesn't have a segue called "second". Also, it doesn't look like your controller is embedded in a navigation controller, so you can't use a push segue. If that controller you show on the left is the initial controller in the storyboard, you don't need to do anything in code to get it on screen. It should just show up when you start (which means you don't need anything in the app delegate at startup).

Comment: I'm only changing the initial screen whenever the user is running the app on an iPhone 5, so how would I change this around so it switches properly on startup?